# Need to add a "Resource Tag" in a "Launch Template" before Launching an AWS instance from CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a "Launch Template" which I use to create AWS instances from the AWS UI. Before creating an instance we just need to update a "Resource tag" in the template which is called "hostid" and then we hit "Launch Instance". The "hostid" resource tag will be used to build the actual FQDN of the instance and hence I have to update it every time I launch a new instance. Here is an example:

[image]

I have been able to call the "Launch Template" from the CLI and it works. However I have not figured how to add (or update) the hostid "Resource tag" from CLI, because of that I have to update the Tag manually in the UI which defeats the purpose of using the CLI.

Any Idea how to add or update a "Resource tag" in a "Launch Template" from the CLI or from a scriptable place?

Thanks!

Comment: I see, I think you want to change a tag of LT itself? Yes.

Comment: This is not a "Template Tag". It is a "Resource Tag" or at least that is what the AWS UI is saying

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a Launch Template (LTs) as LTs are **immutable**. Instead, you have to create a [new version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchTemplates.html) of it:

> After you create your launch template, you can create a **new version** and add the AMI and user data that has the latest version of your application for testing.

You do this using [create-launch-template-version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-launch-template-version.html) CLI command. Using this command you can specify `TagSpecifications`:

> **The tags to apply to the resources during launch**. You can only tag instances and volumes on launch. The specified tags are applied to all instances or volumes that are created during launch. To tag a resource after it has been created, see CreateTags .

Comment: Are you sure? How come from UI I do not need to create a new version of the Launch template ? I just edit the tag and click in "Launch Instance"

Comment: @LuisSerrano The AWS console creates the new version. It does not change the existing one. But if you check carefully, you will see that any change results in a new LT version.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @marcin but I do not see a new Launch Template version every time I update the Tag. Also I need to create like 200 VM's and I do not think having 200 versions of the Launch Template will scale.